# Spring: Send HTML mail

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, html-email

I want to create a service to send an HTML mail using Spring email with [`MimeMessage`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html). Here is my service:

```
    public void sendHtmlEmail(String receiver,String Subject, String htmlBody) throws MessagingException {

            MimeMessage msg = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

            // true = multipart message
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, false);

            helper.setTo(receiver);

            helper.setSubject(Subject);

            // true = text/html
            helper.setText(htmlBody, true);


            javaMailSender.send(msg);
        }
```

The problem is that I don't receive an email in html but tags in html,knowing that I put true in the method [`setText()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#setText-java.lang.String-boolean-) ! the email I send is displayed in plain html text like following

```
<html><h1>some text !</h1></html>
```

some links that could help you:

https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-send-email-via-smtp/

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email

here's the application.properties :

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=username
spring.mail.password=password

# Other properties
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000

# TLS , port 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

and the controller

```
@PostMapping("/htmlMail")
    public String sendHtmlMail(@RequestBody MailDTO mail) {
        mailService.sendHtmlEmail(mail.getReceiver(),mail.getSubject(),mail.getHtmlbody());
        return "html E-Mail Sent ! ";
    }
```

Comment: set `properties.put("mail.debug", "true");` into your `JavaMailSender` bean, to see exactly what headers and payload is transmitted.

Comment: Code seems to be ok. Maybe you can try another version to be sure that's not a bug with your current version.

Comment: I also seem your code is OK. Try to add encoding type "UTF-8" in MimeMessageHelper Object. Can you provide some more detail about your code or error snap? Or try solution i place in answer hope so it is helpful.

Comment: well when i set the option debug to true i get Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 ! this is not what i want (I put true in the method setText() so i should have html type ) :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime required parameter is not there so it gives an error. In your question not whole code or error snep is given so i describe on my way.

Check following two points first,

1. All required configuration data are provided.
2. Your email id must have permission to send mail using your application (Allow "less secure app" in your gmail account - if you're using).

---

### Yml Properties file

```
mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com                   // Take based on your mail provider
    port: 587
    username: *@gmail.com
    password: ****
    transport:
      protocol: smtp
    properties:
      test-connection: true
      debug: true
      smtp:
        auth: true
        starttls:
          enable: true
          required: true
        ssl:
          enable: true
```

---

### Code Snippet

```
   @Autowired
   JavaMailSender mailSender;

   public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String content, boolean 
    isMultipart, boolean isHtml){

      MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

      JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
      mailSender.setHost(EMAIL_HOST);
      mailSender.setPort(EMAIL_PORT);
      mailSender.setUsername(EMAIL_USERNAME);
      mailSender.setPassword(EMAIL_PASSWORD);

      Properties properties = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
      properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", Boolean.TRUE);
      properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
      properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", Boolean.TRUE);
      properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", Boolean.TRUE);
      properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", Boolean.FALSE);
      properties.put("mail.test-connection", Boolean.TRUE);
      properties.put("mail.debug", Boolean.TRUE);

      mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);

      try {
        MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, isMultipart, "UTF-8");
        messageHelper.setFrom(USER_EMAIL);
        messageHelper.setTo(to);
        messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
        messageHelper.setText(content, isHtml);
        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.warn("Email could not be sent to user '{}': {}", to, ex.getMessage());
      }
    }
```

---

### For Call

```
    @Async
    public void sendTestingMail(String mail) {
      String subject = "Test mail from Project Management System";
      String content = "<h1>Be happy, Enjoy Life...!!!</h1>";
      sendMail(mail, subject, content, false, true);
    }
```

Email kind of configuration you set up once and use multiple place so try to do single full setup.

Have a nice day...!!!

Comment: Well i verify these two points you mentioned , but still the same old problem

Comment: yes of course ! i added the controller and the application.properties

Comment: Okay i'll update you after checking same code in my machine.