# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.MailSender'

Tags: java, spring, configuration, javabeans, spring-context

I am trying to use MailSender in my ApplicationListener, by autowiring it SpringContext:

```
package example.util.emailUtil;

@Component
public class PostUserListener implements ApplicationListener<OnPostUserDataEvent> {

@Autowired
private MailSender mailSender;
}
```

Configuration-class is:

```
 @ComponentScan(basePackages ={"example.util.emailUtil","example.model","example.service"})
 @Configuration
 public class MailProvider {

   @Bean(name = "mailSender")
   public MailSender javaMailService() 
    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    javaMailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    javaMailSender.setPort(587);
    javaMailSender.setProtocol("smtp");
    javaMailSender.setUsername("sender’s email");
    javaMailSender.setPassword("sender’s password");
    Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
    javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);
    return javaMailSender;
   }
 }
```

But I catch the following exeption:

```
 NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.MailSender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidat
```

Comment: `return new new JavaMailSenderImpl();` do you really have two `new` keyword or its a typo in the post?

Comment: Rather use JavaMailSender, instead of MailSender.

Comment: Try this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59852778/9437031

Comment: Karthikeyan Vaithilingam, its a typo. I edited this

Answer (score 0):

1. Check below things in your application.properties

   ```
   spring.mail.host=smtp.xxx.com
   spring.mail.username=xxx@xxx.com
   spring.mail.password=xxxxx
   spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
   spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
   spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
   ```
2. If you are using spring boot application, use @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation 
   which will help to auto configure.

Comment: VIKASH, the containt of bean was ommited in my answer. And now I eddited my answer by adding properties

Answer (score 0):

It does not consider your MailSender class as a class that can be annotated with @autowired or as a bean that we can inject. And check if you added an @component, @service or other annotation to it.
Perhaps there will be other errors. This one comes from there.